# Is c:\bootmgr necessary in Win2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, boot

I was writing an MSBuild script to automate my build. In my script I defined the following:

```
  <DeleteBeforeBuild Include="$(WebOutputFolder)\*" />
```

Since I had not previously declared `WebOutputFolder` it used `\*` as the folder I wanted to clear out.

When I ran the script, it said pagefile.sys was currently being used by another process. That's when I realized I told it to delete everything starting from the root! My only salvation was that having pagefile.sys open by another process aborted the script.

I took a look at other servers to see what I could have possibly deleted and I see that I am missing c:\bootmgr. Now I'm afraid to restart thinking it won't boot up.

So my question... is bootmgr needed? If so, how can I recreate it? I see that the bootmgr file is different size on the different servers, so this file is probably specific to each machine, which would prevent me from just copying it to my build machine.

I also see that in my build machine I do not have c:\Boot, which is on the other server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On 2008 R2 you won't normally have a C:\Boot or a C:\Bootmgr.  You can verify the location of the boot manager and windows loader by running BCDedit with no switches from an elevated command prompt.  On a clean 2008 R2 MBR install I get:

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {0a38afb2-2263-11e3-9f8e-c1b384c483b5}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
 -------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows Server 2008 R2
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {0a38afb4-2263-11e3-9f8e-c1b384c483b5}
recoveryenabled         Yes
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {0a38afb2-2263-11e3-9f8e-c1b384c483b5}
nx                      OptOut
```

The Bootmgr location Device\HarddiskVolume1 corresponds to the 100mb 'System Reserved' partition created at install.

Comment: I ran BCDedit and got the same value for "device". Thank you!